# how can i fit search text field and search button in div(div A) where div (div A) is in another div(div B) which has 100% width

Tags: html, css

[i want to do like this]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOSKk.png

I have created a div(div B) in body that has 100% width and it has another div (div A) which has two components in it.the Div A is not able to get width of only two elements its getting 100% width.

This is my code

```html
 <div id="con"> <div id="srbt"> <input id="srch" type="text" placeholder="Paste Youtube link" name="search"> <button id="btn">Download</button></div> </div>
```

Comment: plz can you add your code so we can help?

Comment: <div id="con"> <div id="srbt"> <input id="srch" type="text" placeholder="Paste Youtube link" name="search"> <button id="btn">Download</button></div> </div>

Comment: good but plz add it in the question so everyone can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#con {
  display:block;
  background: #502c6c;
  height:125px;
  width:100%;
  padding:30px;
}

#srbt {
  width:100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  height:65px;
  border-radius:5px;
  position:relative;
}

#srch {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    height:65px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:0 20% 0 5%;
    line-height:65px;
    color:#6c7592;
    font-size:20px;
}

#btn {
  background:#ff5916;
  border:none;
  border-radius:5px;
  height:59px;
  width:20%;
  position:absolute;
  top:3px;
  right:3px;
  z-index:10;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="con"> 
  <div id="srbt"> 
    <input id="srch" type="text" placeholder="Paste Youtube link" name="search"> 
    <button id="btn">Start</button>
  </div> 
</div>
```